# Passing two arguments in link

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I have a page in my project management app where I list all the tickets that the user owns (which all belongs to a project). In the template I have a link to show a specific ticket, but it doesn't seem to work because the following error is thrown:

```
Reverse for 'show_ticket' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

As you can see in url pattern below I need both the project_id (that the ticket belongs to) as well as the ticket_id. How can I get this to work?

**from template:**

```
<a href="{% url show_ticket ticket.id %}">{{ ticket }}</a>
```

**from urls.py:**

```
url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/ticket/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)/$', 'project_app.views.show_ticket', name="show_ticket"),
```

**the ticket models:**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
...other fields...
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="projects")
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your urlconf uses named (keyword) arguments:

```
<a href="{% url show_ticket project_id=ticket.project_id ticket_id=ticket.id %}">{{ ticket }}</a>
```

[Url tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)